# Create ant target with command line arguments

Tags: ant, arguments, command-line-arguments, target

I'm doing an ant XML to manage repositories and some stuff, and I want to run a target passing command line arguments like this :

```
ant deploy-stable 0.0.1
```

How can I configure my target to receive "0.0.1" as argument ?

```
<target name="deploy-stable">
    <!-- Run git targets, previously defined, using the version passed by command line --> 
</target>
```

Comment: I find a way to do this using command line `ant -Dversion 0.0.1 deploy-stable`, have another way to run without "-Dversion" ?

Comment: Sounds like you want it as a property in ant, and that is exactly what -D does.  There isn't another way to specify properties directly on the command line according to apache.  https://ant.apache.org/manual/running.html#options .  If you explain why you are looking for another way, it might lead to some ideas.